# ARKit - Adding texture to object in Scene Editor

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, blender

This would be working perfectly if it weren't for one aspect of what is going on. When I add the texture to the object (drag and drop it onto the object from the menu in the bottom right) it adds it exactly where I want, but it also adds it around the object large (too large for the object) and all blurred, and I want it to just stay white:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I want it to stay in the middle where it is, and have the surrounding area be the original color of the shirt.

**UPDATE**

I created a `static` physics body, and that allowed me to get to the materials of the `Plane` object. But I can't remove the coloring around the image.

**UPDATE**

Also, I exported the texture from `Blender` with `Save Image As` from Blender `UV/Image Editor`, I'm not sure if that is the correct way to export a texture to be used correctly in xcode.

**UPDATE**

I used the .obj file instead and got this far, but when it renders in the app there is no image, only they gray tshirt.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export a `.dae` including textures from `Blender`, make sure to select `UV Textures` and the `Copy` checkbox unter `Texture Options`, in the `Export` options, during export. Then, in xcode, your texture will be available as a material under the `Materials` tab, and you just have to drag the image that you were using with the texture, onto the material (make sure you have the correct `material` selected) in the `Scene Editor` in `Xcode`.